# Code Mirror - Make a given line completely greyed out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, codemirror

I'm working with Code Mirror and I'm trying to make a given line completely greyed out (so it looks like a comment usually looks like in code editors). So far I've come up with this:

```
editorDiv = this;

var editor = CodeMirror(function(elt) {
  editorDiv.parentNode.replaceChild(elt, editorDiv);
}, {
  value:       "function myScript(){\n\treturn 100; \n}\n",
  lineNumbers: true,
  readOnly:    "nocursor",
  theme:       "monokai"
});

console.log(editor);

var line = editor.getLineHandle(1);
console.log(line);

editor.addLineClass(line, "text", "greyed-out");
```

Let's say I want the `return 100;` line to be greyed out (which is line 2 in the editor and line 1 as per the API). My idea was to add the `greyed-out` class to this line and having the class be something like:

```
.greyed-out { color: grey; }
```

However, this does not work since there are other classes from Code Mirror which have higher priority and overwrite the `greyed-out` class.

I'm not sure if there's a specific way to do this through Code Mirror's API, or a general way to remove the unwanted attributes from the higher priority classes.

Could someone give me some help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to over-ride a rule from another class is to give your selector a higher specificity, for example:

```css
#container .foo-list li .greyed-out { color: grey; }
```

Alternatively, you could use `!important` on the rule, but this is considered bad practice and should be avoided where at all possible.

```css
.greyed-out { color: grey !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

In such case you can use `!important`:

```
.greyed-out { color: grey !important; }
```

However it shuld be avoided and used only if necessary. You can also increase specificity of your styles by extending selector.